# OpenSIPS log INVITE requests with wrong credentials

Tags: authentication, request, logging, invite

I would like to log all INVITE requests sent by users with wrong authentication details

The problem is that I only need really failed auth INVITE attempts (with wrong username/password), not all requests sent with no credentials (before challenged by OpenSIPS).

Following script logs also requests with no credentials, it would be great if someone will help me to correct it:

```
if (!check_source_address("0")) {
    if (!proxy_authorize("", "subscriber")) {
        xlog("L_ERROR","Auth error for $fU@$fd from $si cause -1 INVITE\n");
        proxy_challenge("", "0");
        exit;
    }
    if (!db_check_from()) {
        sl_send_reply("403","Forbidden, use FROM=ID");
        exit;
    }
    consume_credentials();
    # caller authenticated
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            Hi This code will h
```

elp and this is the working one.

```
            $var(auth_code) = www_authorize("", "subscriber");
            if ( $var(auth_code) == -1 || $var(auth_code) == -2 ) {
            xlog("Authentication failed for $fU@$fd from $si cause $var(auth_code)");
            exit;
            }
            if ( $var(auth_code) < 0 ) {
            www_challenge("", "0");
            exit;
            }

            if (!db_check_to()) {
                    sl_send_reply("403","Forbidden auth ID");
                    exit;
            }

            if(!save("location")) {
                    xlog("Register: Saving contact failed for User $ru from $si");
                    sl_reply_error();
                    exit;
            }
            xlog( "User $fU Registered/Unregisterd Successfully From IP:$si");
            exit;
```